# Ajax play audio file only once

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I have a simple problem that I cant solve. The logic should work, but for some reason its not working. Basically I have an ajax call which checks a status every 5 or so seconds.what I want to do is call an audio file only once!

Unfortunately, this simple issue seems to be harder then I thought...

Can anyone tell me know I am going wrong?

Ajax function calls handleFencing...

```
status = true;

function handleFencing(){
    if(status = true) {
        var snd = new Audio("sounds/beep.wav"); 
        snd.play();
        status = false;
     }
     else{}

}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Ryan

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning `true` to `status` not comparing

Should be

```
if(status == true) {
```

instead of

```
if(status = true) {
```

`=` is an assignment operator

`==` comparison operator

Comment: Thanks for the input Suman! Ive done that mistake twice now. Unfortunately im not getting any audio now. The logic makes sense but code does not seems to work...

Comment: can put your `html` and `js` into jsfiddle?